# Alignment issue

Tags: html, css

Could someone please help me with this alignment issue?

So everything is all over the place and I don't know how to align everything, move the button closer to the line divider and then align everything with the last menu button 'Home' underneath it.

Would really appreciate someone looking at this and showing me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I recommend using either FireBug plugin from Firefox or Chrome and the Inspect Element feature. This will allow you to hover over elements within the page and view the real estate it's taking up and what the settings are dependent on. You can also make real-time changes to both the tags and the CSS styles and see what kind of effect it has on the outcome.

Next, set your .nav-login style width to 75px and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: Hi, yes that will align the 'client' button, but does not solve the issue with line seperator being to far away. Also I would think that this need to be recoded as I don't think it being in DIV's is correct and should be in LI instead so help on sorting all this section out would be appreciated.

Comment: Soted out divider also via padding alignment. Can someone tell me if the div set up is okay, or should I be using liv as best practice??? If so can anyone assist me in changing over div's to li's please.

Comment: It's my understanding that div is the common practice now, though I'm not exactly a web-designer. I just know enough to know what I'm doing and fix problems I seem to invent for myself. ;-)